# How to determine limiting conductivity of specific ions?

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, conductivity

Given a table with equivalent conductivity of certain electrolytes, how can I determine the conductivity of separate ions? I know that you can find the difference between for example $\ce{K+}$ and $\ce{Na+}$ if you know the limiting conductivity of $\ce{KOH}$ and $\ce{NaOH}$, but how do you calculate the actual value for those two ions?

EDIT:
I've found a different source for the table, my apologies. Let me rephrase my question. Many texts on electrolytic conductivity refer to a table containing the molar conductivity of individual ions, ([2](http://www.fondriest.com/environmental-measurements/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/DOW.pdf)). What I'm wondering is, how are these values obtained? Can they be calculated with data from ([1](http://sites.chem.colostate.edu/diverdi/all_courses/CRC%20reference%20data/equivalent%20conductivity%20of%20electrolytes.pdf))?

Comment: Apologies, I picked that table from the first image I could find on google. I've updated my question now.

Comment: The Colorado State one was fine, it was just the "homework as a service" one that was a bit suspect.  Sometimes people spam sites like that on SE to get search engine recognition, so I tend to err on the side of caution.  Thanks for your attention to the question!